# Combining rows with similar IDs and same dates mysql

Tags: mysql

Need some assistance with a mysql syntax. I have a list of thousands of transactions.

The member ID is unique to the individual. The first 7 digits are unique to a family (the last two digits are for the specific individual in the family).

I need to group by family and add their transactions to the main member of the family (01) as long as they were done on the same date.

**Before**

```
ID                Date    Amt

 1. 888888801         0715    $100
 2. 888888802         0715    $50 
 3. 888888802         0720    $300
 4. 777777701         0715    $250
 5. 666666601         0630    $75
 6. 666666604         0630    $100 
 7. 555555502         0701    $99
```

2 goes with 1, 6 goes with 5.

**After**

```
 - ID                Date    Amt

 1. 888888801         0715    $150
 3. 888888802         0720    $300
 4. 777777701         0715    $250
 5. 666666601         0630    $175
 7. 555555502         0701    $99
```

Comment: You should consider normalizing your table; add family in a separate column.

Comment: If you can, redesign your data. This can cost some time now, but save much time later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this

```
SELECT id, date, sum(amount) FROM myTable
GROUP BY date, LEFT(`id`,7)
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30588/3)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't redesign these tables, and if I'm following you right, this might be what you want:

```
SELECT LEFT(`id`,7) as Family, `date`, SUM(`amt`) as `amt`
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY LEFT(`id`,7), `Date` 
ORDER BY `id`
```